# Where are the Thronebreaker save files located?

Tags: thronebreaker-the-witcher-tales

I'm playing Thronebreaker: The Witcher Tales and I want to put my save files in Dropbox, which is what I usually do with all games, especially in light of [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/gwent/comments/9r9f4v/thronebreaker_save_data_gone/) where players claim that their save files have been lost. However I haven't been able to locate the save files on my computer, not in My Documents nor in the installation folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save location: C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\CDProjektRED\Thronebreaker\SaveData

Credit to u/deamon59 for this info.

Answer (score 3):

This is a copy-pasteable path: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\CDProjektRED\Thronebreaker\SaveData`